# Bolding first word of xml node

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, api, twitter

I'm Learning some AS3 and I'm trying to Build a Twitter Application, I'm facing a Problem with XML Retrieved from Twitter RSS API.

I want to Bold out the First Word in the Child Node. I tried many setTextFormat ways but Neither worked with me since I'm New to the whole thing.

The Code That Display the Updates is:

```
for each (var nodo:XML in twitter..item) { 
    myUpdates += 
        "<a href='" + 
        nodo.link + 
        "'><font color='#CC3300'>" +
        nodo.title.substr(0,50) + 
        "..." + 
        "</font></a><br>" + 
        "<font color='#000000'>" +
        nodo.pubDate +
        "</font><br/><br/>"; 
}
```

I managed to subtract the 140 Tweet to 50 Characters "substr(0,50)".

I just want to Bold up the First Word in the "title".

any Ideas? Please Help.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1):

To bold the first word in a string you can do this:

```
var s:String = "This is a string of words";

// Split the string into an array using the space character as a delimiter.
// (Every word is separated by a space.)
var words:Array = s.split(" ");

var firstWord:String = words[0];

// Remove the first word from the array and join the remaining 
// words back into a string.
words.unshift();
var followingWords = words.join(" ");

var formattedString = "<b>" + firstWord + "</b> " + followingWords;
```

Comment: Thanks @bwroga for the Answer, but I can't control the title in the xml, but I already declared it as

'code' var TwitterUser:String = twitter.child(0).title; 

The Username is word[0] in <title> node.

Comment: @MoeKaakati I'm sorry, but I don't understand the problem. Could you post a sample of the xml?

Comment: ... And tell me which word should be bolded?

Comment: This is the XML URL:
[link](http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=SteamCloudInc)

the word SteamCloudInc inside <item><title> Node.

Comment: @MoeKaakati I think the example I provided would work. Just replace "This is a string of words" with "nodo.title.substr(0, 50)" and put the code inside of your for loop at the beginning. Then replace "nodo.title.substr(0, 50)" (in your string concatenation statement) with "formattedString".

Comment: @wvxvw: That is smart. You should make that an answer.